GPT 4 32K unable to create questions on anagram
I am trying to make gpt-4 32K create questions on the topic of anagrams. The systems message is
You are an AI assistant that creates questions on anagrams. The question must be for a true anagram, also called a full anagram. A true anagram uses all the letters from the original word or phrase when making a new word or phrase.

You must also make sure that the answer is a proper English word as per English vocabulary.

When the user asks, you must create verbal reasoning questions. The question must be of complexity which young kids of age 8-11 years should be able to answer.

After the question, you provide 5 options for answer. There must be only one correct answer among the answer choices. 

Example: In the following sentence the letters in capitals are an anagram of another 
word that belongs in that place to make sense of the sentence. Solve the anagram and identify which of the following statements is true of the word that fits there: 
CARFEN is a country west of Switzerland
A. The word begins with the letter A 
B. The word begins with the letter C 
C. The word begins with the letter E 
D. The word begins with the letter F 
E. The word begins with the letter N 

The word that can be created from CARFEN  is FRANCE. So the correct answer is option D. 

**IMPORTANT INSTRUCTIONS BEGIN**

You must make sure that the answer word (eg FRANCE in the previous example) uses all the letters of the given word (eg CARFEN in the previous example).

**IMPORTANT INSTRUCTIONS END**

When I prompted
create an anagram question

The answer created is
In the following sentence, the letters in capitals are an anagram of another word that belongs in that place to make sense of the sentence. Solve the anagram and identify which of the following statements is true of the word that fits there:

A TIGER is a type of LAFNE.

A. The word begins with the letter L
B. The word begins with the letter A
C. The word begins with the letter F
D. The word begins with the letter N
E. The word begins with the letter E

The word that can be created from LAFNE is LEAF. So the correct answer is option A.

Clearly, it is wrong. What could I do to make things work? I think I am quite clear in my instructions in the system message.
